# Переклад фрази "It rains cats and dogs"

Tags: переклад, from-english

Цікавить, як перекласти фразу "It rains cats and dogs".

Google перекладач подає як ["Дощить котів і собак"](https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=uk&text=It%20rains%20cats%20and%20dogs)

Розумію, що це не правильно, але як перекласти не знаю. 
Який правильний переклад?

Comment: https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/4285707/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%89-%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%94-%D1%8F%D0%BA-%D1%96%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Це англійська ідіома, найкраще буде замінити її українським еквівалентом. Спершу подивимося визначення цієї ідіоми у [Кембріджському словнику](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/it-s-raining-cats-and-dogs):

> Вживаємо, щоб описати сильний дощ.

Найкращим варіантом буде фразеологізм "**Ллє як із/з відра**". Такий варінат перекладу ми бачимо на форумі [Duolingo](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/4285707/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%89-%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%94-%D1%8F%D0%BA-%D1%96%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0), а також на сайті [GreenForest](https://greenforest.com.ua/journal/read/anglijski-prislivya-ta-ih-ekvivalenti-v-ukrainskij-movi) (де, також вказується, що дослівний переклад неможливий).